# Capture Wrong Password Event on Apple Script

Tags: applescript

Is it possible to capture the "Wrong Password" message when logging into a Mac using AppleScript?

I looked in the Dictionary -> System Events, but didn't find what I'm looking for.

I would like to create a security system that takes a picture of the user when a wrong password is entered + some stuff (like using iMessage to notify).

Since this is also for learning purpose, I would like to know how to use AppleScript, and not install an app that do the same thing.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm almost certain an Applescript process needs to be run under a user account. If you're not logged in yet, I don't believe it's possible to so much as run an Applescript command (this can be demonstrated when trying to use osascript from Single User Mode).

Comment: Thanks Josh for your Reply. Seems logic! But what if I'm already logged in and the Mac goes to lock screen after being inactive?

Comment: After a quick bout of googling it looks like Applescript will stop running when the computer locks. However, using a third party program like SleepWatcher (https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10387/sleepwatcher) you could potentially start an Applescript, though I'm not sure if then the Applescript would run or return a timeout error as it does when trying to run without SleepWatcher

Comment: I ended up with the same conclusion. SleepWatcher seems a good tool for doing the trick. You should publish your previous comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You could always run that through your own app (built with Xcode) so it's a non issue.
Have you discovered how to fetch the "Wrong Password" thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick bout of googling it looks like Applescript will stop running when the computer locks. However, using a third party program like [SleepWatcher](http://macupdate.com/app/mac/10387/sleepwatcher) you could potentially start an Applescript, though I'm not sure if then the Applescript would run or return a timeout error as it does when trying to run without SleepWatcher. Best of luck!